# Postgres XMLTABLE with missing nodes

Tags: postgresql, xmltable

Assume Table A with an XML field.  Table A has two rows, with the following XML data in the table.

Row 1

```
<fullname>
  <firstName>John</firstName>
  <lastName>Smith</lastName>
</fullname>
```

and Row 2

```
<fullname>
  <firstName>Jane</firstName>
</fullname>
```

This query:

```
SELECT * FROM A 
  XMLTABLE(('/fullname'::text) PASSING (a.xml) 
  COLUMNS firstName text PATH ('firstName'::text), lastName text PATH ('lastName'::text)) a
```

will only return data on John and not Jane.  Is there a work around for this?

Comment: Not sure what your question is, but your query (once the implicit cross join is fixed by adding a comma) it does return two rows: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8e6942317f6d0e32fa64393102ec968a

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-xml.html

"default *X*" resolved the issue.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.